# Auth0 On login, js callback instead of redirect

Tags: javascript, auth0

in the login popup, after the user loges in or registers, he is redirected to auth0 and then back to my application.

what I want to do is instead of redirecting, just to get a javascript call back. so I could add some data to the user (e.g. connect his shopping cart...)
is that possible?

I thought of a solution where I just pass an identification with the AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL but I hopping to not do this..

thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer in auth0 support forum:

https://ask.auth0.com/forum/t/on-login-js-callback-instead-of-redirect/2865

> rolodato: We strongly recommend using redirect mode whenever
>   possible, since popup mode (allows JS callbacks) has several drawbacks
>   which have no workaround. You can read about how to use the different
>   modes here: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/authentication-modes